# How to Connect Kindle Fire to ADB while in "Kindle Fire System Recovery"

Tags: unbricking, amazon-kindle-fire

I have a Kindle Fire HD (tate) that I bricked by modding /system/app/Framework-Res.apk and I am trying to unbrick it. How can I connect it to ADB? It won't show up in Ubuntu or Windows. It is in a bootloop with a red triangle and it prompts to system restore (doesn't work). It doesn't have TWRP because I used iRoot. It looks similar to this image.

[image: Similar to this image.]

Is this possible? If so, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You need a driver built by amazon to connect it to ADB. This should help you: https://developer.amazon.com/public/community/post/Tx3RZFBU0KJTSWS/Setting-up-the-ADB-Driver-for-Kindle-Fire-Devices